# what is persistance layer ?

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, persistence

I ve been doing   research on Google about n tier application and various layers like data layer , presentation layer ,service layer also came across persistence layer.. I have no clue where this fellow fits fine in a enterprise application with .net and entity framework. Also people relate persistence layer with caching . they say caching is aspect skipped in applications using EF. Also saw somewhere java code has some persistence thing EJB ..

Can anyone shed light on this persistence layer ?

Answer (score 2):

Persistence layer includes code that interacts with database system.In OOP language Objects are stored as rows in Table.Persistence layer retrieves Object from Database and can insert/update/delete data object in Database.In EJB-3.0 there is JPA (Java Persistence API) that deals with DB interaction.

Comment: Yes you can say hibernate , JPA , Entity framework of EJB-2.X , iBatis these all are persistence frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Application Layer that performs database operations is some times called persistence layer. Primary function of this layer is to interact with database (Read/Write).